# php and soap headers token auth

Tags: php, soap, soapheader

I need this xml in out:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="https://server/">
<soapenv:Header>
<authenticate>111111111111</authenticate>
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
```

My php code is:

```
$head = new stdClass();
$head->authenticate='1111111111111111';
$header = new SoapHeader('ns1','authenticate',$head,false);
$client = new SoapClient ('https://server',array("trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 1));
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

I get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="https://server" 
xmlns:ns2="https://server">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
<ns2:authenticate>
<authenticate><BOGUS>anc401t9n4dknmgp2bv629ori7</BOGUS>
</authenticate></ns2:authenticate>
</SOAP-ENV:Header
><SOAP-ENV:Body>...
```

How can I get needed xml? Can fully rewrite soapheader with php client SoapClient? Or how I can adding one string whithout creating new namespace?

Answer (score 0):

If your Web Service is well documented within its WSDL, try using [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com) or [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) as it generates the methods to properly set the SoapHeader very easily and so for the whole request.